# Using DELETE and UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables such that

```
CREATE TABLE guest(
    name varchar(100),
    ranking int,
    PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE room(
    roomname varchar(100),
    wallcolor varchar(100),
    rating int,
    PRIMARY KEY(roomnane)
);

CREATE TABLE reservation(
    name varchar(100),
    roomname varchar(100),
    day varchar(100),
    moveinday int,
    moveoutday int,
    PRIMARY KEY(roomname, day, start, finish),
    FOREIGN KEY(roomname) REFERENCES room(roomname),
    FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES guest(name)
);
```

1. I am trying to a write a query to delete all guests who are not qualified to rent any rooms, together with their reservations. Qualified to rent means the guests rating is greater than or equal to room rating.

   I have tried the following

   ```
   DELETE FROM guests, reservations
   WHERE guests.rating <  rooms.rating
   ```

   This is not accomplishing the task. What could I be doing wrong? I need to maintain referential integrity.
2. I'm trying to change all the "Lake" rooms to "Bay" rooms and "Bay" rooms to "Lake" rooms without explicitly changing the rooms involved. How could I do this? I tried using the update query but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Two totally different questions should be asked as . . . two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM guests, reservations
WHERE guests.rating <  rooms.rating
```

You have no table `guests`. Change to `guest`. And table `guest` has no field `rating` only `ranking`.
Check your code carefuly!

Comment: does this also delete from reservations?

Comment: if you have got cascade option, it could. check and write here